# Using sed to output only single word listed before a comma

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm learning sed and have come close to arriving at a solution for a the following problem:

> Print the lines of all Oceania countries that have a one word name
>   (example: print Australia but not Solomon Islands)

Command:

```
sed -n -e 's/\(.*\)\(,OC,\)\(.*\)/\1/p' countries
```

Output:

```
American Samoa
Australia
Cook Islands
Fiji
Micronesia
Guam
Kiribati
Marshall Islands
Northern Mariana Islands
New Caledonia
Norfolk Island
Nauru
Niue
New Zealand
French Polynesia
Papua New Guinea
Pitcairn
Palau
Solomon Islands
Tokelau
Tonga
Tuvalu
United States Minor Outlying Islands
Vanuatu
Wallis and Futuna
Samoa
```

I would like to know how to used sed to achieve the following in separate commands:

- remove lines with spaces
- remove lines with no spaces

I'm also curious to know what the proper character for `<TAB>` is in sed, especially with a command like:

```
sed 's/,/<TAB>/'
```

I've seen the `<Control-V><TAB>` trick, but is there any characters set that can be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[[:space:]]/d' file # removes lines with space(s)
```

and

```
sed '/[[:space:]]/!d' file # removes lines with no space(s)
```

to replace a comma with a tab use:

```
sed 's/,/\t/' file
```

or all commas with tabs use:

```
sed 'y/,/\t/' file
```

Comment: This can be some dangerous.  If a line have space after it, it will be deleted.  Hard do see what went wrong.

Comment: I combined your short hand code with my selection and got the correct output using: sed -n -e '/[[:space:]]/d;s/\(.*\)\(,OC,\)\(.*\)/\1/p' countries

Answer (score 2):

I know you are asking for `sed`, but sometime other program may do the job fine like `awk` in this case.
This will work with both tab and space and multiple space/tabs.

```
awk 'NF==1' file
Australia
Fiji
Micronesia
Guam
Kiribati
Nauru
Niue
Pitcairn
Palau
Tokelau
Tonga
Tuvalu
Vanuatu
Samoa
```

It prints all line with only one field.

---

With more than one field.

```
awk 'NF!=1'
American Samoa
Cook Islands
Marshall Islands
Northern Mariana Islands
New Caledonia
Norfolk Island
New Zealand
French Polynesia
Papua New Guinea
Solomon Islands
United States Minor Outlying Islands
Wallis and Futuna
```

This should even work:

```
awk NF==1 file
```

Comment: Thanks, for this project I limited to sed. I'm trying to understand the sed program.

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing spaces before deleting lines with a space

```
sed -e 's/ *$//' -e '/ / d'
```

(looks like `grep -v " "`).